# Complex integration over a general ellipse

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm having trouble evaluating the complex integral over an ellipse :

$\int_C{\dfrac{1}{z^{4} + 1}} dz$

where C is the ellipse given by $x^{2} - xy + y^{2} + x + y = 0$. How should I go about it?

Comment: If you want to evaluate the integral directly, i.e. transform it into a riemann (or lebesgue) integral and compute that integral's value, then yes. If you want to use the residue theorem, then you only need to find out which of the poles if your integrand $\frac{1}{z^4+1}$ lie within your ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to work this out is to figure out which poles of the integrand lie within the given ellipse, and then compute the residues at those poles.  The poles lie at

$$(x,y) = \left (\pm \frac1{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right )$$

A point $(x,y)$ lies within the ellipse when $x^2-x y+y^2+x+y<0$.  Plug in each of these four poles and show that only the pole at $ \left (- \frac1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right )$ is inside, i.e. $z=-e^{i \pi/4}$.  Thus the integral is

$$\frac{i 2 \pi}{-4 e^{i 3 \pi/4}} = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{i 3 \pi/4}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply ! I also tried solving by breaking the function down using partial fractions and verified that i get the same answer.